Low $R^2$ puzzle
I conducted an experiment and using the data I fitted a basic linear regression model. The top chart displays the fit. The $R^2$ is abysmally low indicating almost no explanatory power (adjusted $R^2$ is even lower). When I plot however the averages of y values for each group of x values I can see the linear relation very clearly. Average of group #7 is a lot higher than average of group #2. Normally I would have tossed this regression based on metrics like F-stat (2.253), $R^2$, t-stat of the explanatory variable. But clearly it is telling me that being in a higher group number is an improvement. The differences in group means are evident and also increase with group number. I am a little puzzled. Is the regression analysis failing me, or am I interpreting the results wrong?


Average of group #7 is a lot higher than average of group #2 A lot higher? Looks higher by .01 on a scale ranging from -.3 to 3, which looks to me like an absolutely tiny difference. Put confidence intervals around the means to see how much certainty you actually have in their pattern.

@Noah in the domain I am dealing those differences are in fact huge. It is not a visual issue. My problem is I was about to conclude that there is no useful relation based on regression statistics.

Do the group numbers have a numerical/quantitative meaning?

@ChristianHennig yes they are not simply group names, they are actually real numbers (I just scaled them).

There does appear to be a strong relationship between the conditional variance of the response and the explanatory variable.   (You can test that in many ways; most of them rely on analyzing the absolute values of the residuals.)  On the face of it, the variation in condition means is not large in the context of the much greater variation of the conditional means, regardless of how large and meaningful this might be in your application.

@whuber yes I can deal with the heteroscedasticity. I just need to look at the correct statistic before disregarding this regression altogether. ChristianHennig suggested I stick to the t-stat of the slope.

Because the heteroscedasticity is so clear and so large, that t-stat would be unreliable unless it were computed with a suitable weighted regression.  You could (on a post hoc basis!) test the hypothesis of a monotonically changing mean response using a simple non-parametric test.  E.g., the permutation test has a p-value of $2^{-4}=0.0625.$ Because this is post hoc it's not reliable, but you could justify it by showing it persists (I presume) among almost any random split of the data into training and test portions.

@whuber this comment was very useful. thank you. my heteroscedasticity is very clear, variance is linear in X and actually I have some additional data to estimate the error variance. So I removed the heteroscedasticity by dividing X and y by the standard deviation and performed OLS. $R^2$ is now 0.01, and t-stat is 3.48 (as opposed to 2.52 before). Does it matter if use WLS directly?

Because there are ample data to demonstrate and characterize the heteroscedasticity, you ought to obtain approximately equivalent results using any suitable procedure.  (Your approach improves on the permutation test by exploiting information about the variability.) What you describe sounds like it's nearly equivalent to WLS.  It differs principally in that the SDs in each group are separately estimated.  Note that even a tiny $R^2$ can be significant evidence of a relation with large data sizes.

Those differences are not huge, they are tiny. This is so, regardless of what your domain says.
If you look at your plot, you see that there is almost no difference across groups and that the difference that does exist is overwhelmed by the differences within  groups.
In addition, you have heterosedasticity, which violates an assumption of linear regression but, here, that is not really the issue.
The regression analysis isn't failing you, the data are. You have a lot of noise. Maybe this can be reduced by adding covariates, maybe not. But no method of regression is going to help, if these are all the data you have.
You can, of course, state the means for each group and let readers interpret them for themselves. But I would also add the standard deviations for each group, which would let readers know that you have very noisy data and that any differences in the means should be looked at very skeptically.

+1 signal to noise ratio is low

I agree with what you saying. Yes signal is weak and differences are small. However what’s really bothering me is if this was a statistical fluke as R2 suggests the ordering wouldn’t be so perfect, meaning as x gets larger y gets larger. This is something very important in my opinion and totally overlooked by R2. I sample X axis more granular and the order still remains intact.

Without that dashed red line, I would have said the groups have the same mean (different variances, but the same mean). Do note that the two plots have different y-axis scales, though. If you scale the lower like the upper, I suspect the obvious upward trend will look a lot less obvious. Set the bottom y-axis to the same -0.3 to +0.3. I think this is your mistake leading you to doubt the $R^2$ calculation when the relationship seems to be so obviously strong.

The $R^2$ measures the ratio between variation explained by regression model and the overall variation. $R^2$ is low in a case like this when the systematic difference between means (as modelled by the regression, assuming that you're running a simple linear regression rather than a one-way ANOVA) is low compared to the residual variance. Note that also deviations from linearity between the means contribute to the variation not explained by the model. The data set you show is a case in which the difference between the means (to the extent that this is in line with linearity) is low compared to the residual variance, so the $R^2$ should be low. What this says is that the modelled tendency of the means doesn't explain much of the variability in the data.
This is not in contradiction to the possibility that the difference between means can be large regarding subject matter knowledge and use and meaning of the results. A regression can be meaningful and significant also if $R^2$ is low. Whether this is the case will depend on background information about the data and the situation, and the use you want to make of the results.
The $R^2$ does properly what it is supposed to do here as far as I can see. The problem seems to be that you think that the $R^2$ is a general measure of whether your regression model is good/valid or not, which it isn't. The $R^2$ measures a specific aspect of model fit, and it says nothing about the subject matter meaning of the mean differences, so you shouldn't expect it to do this.

R2 is on the chart. Thanks for your answer. Can I use another tool to detect that linear relationship is there even when explained variance is low? Would ANOVA help for example? My concern is that if this was a statistical fluke based on R2, of F-statistic the ordering would have been distorted as well. But monotony is there even if I sample X more densely. So even if I bring more evidence of monotony I cannot improve the current statistics I use. So what do I need?

@CagdasOzgenc ANOVA is a regression.

@Dave Good to know. I don't know much about ANOVA.

@CagdasOzgenc Is the t-statistic of the regression explanatory variable significant? What is the p-value? If this is significant, you have evidence that the explanatory variable makes a difference (if potentially small).

t-stat (2.523), p-value(0.0117)

@CagdasOzgenc That might be all you need. (Although you might also want to compute a confidence interval; not sure what the application is but depending on this you may question linearity, but this gets you into more complex territory.)

The relationship is linear up to a certain point after that as x get larger y saturates. So I can fit something nonlinear and more appropriate but that is not the issue. I was just giving up altogether with the lousy F-stat, and R^2.
